# Aligning an image with text

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a very basic placeholder site. Centered, in the middle of the page, it should read:

> (COMPANY LOGO) WEBSITE COMING IN 2018

The company logo uses the same font as the text.

By default the image sits alongside the text nicely, however this changes when I attempt to align it centrally.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x100" alt="logo" />
    <h1>WEBSITE COMING IN 2018</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

What would be the most effective way to do this?

Comment: Remember to remove the floats with inline-block. I would also move text-align:center to the header class, unless you want the whole page to be center aligned.

Comment: Obviously this isn't a solution and may well be out of your control, but I think it's worth pointing out that generally it's better to take to user to some existing content, rather than to show a "Website coming soon" page. If it's not built yet, why can the user go there?

Comment: @dbs I get what you mean, but I think the idea is that users can go to the site and sign up for an update when it goes live.

Comment: Fair enough, if the page does offer some functionality then it makes sense. I just have bad memories of the old "Under construction" gifs that used to plague the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this using `flexbox`

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  /* added */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x100" alt="logo" />
    <h1>WEBSITE COMING IN 2018</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` as follows on your `.header`element

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x100" alt="logo" />
    <h1>Website Coming in 2018</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note: the slight vertical offset of the text is due to the space below its baseline which is reserved for letters like j, g , p etc. which extend below the baseline. As soon as you use any of these letters in your text it will be perfectly centered. I changed the uppercase letters to regular text mode to demonstrate this.